# Is there way to print-format this dictionary in a more presentable way?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
product_dict = {"Jeans": 150, "Jacket": 300, "Perfume": 50, "Wallet": 125, "Glasses": 100}
#product dictonary with prices    
order_history = {'Andrew':[{'Jeans':2, 'Wallet': 4}, {'Perfume':2}], 'Max':[{'Jacket': 3}]}
c_name = input('customer name: ')
print('The following is order history of, c_name')
key = order_history['c_name']
for i in range(len(key)):
    print('purchase', i+1, key[i])
```

I am creating a retail check out program, I have a predefined products stored in a dictionary along with prices that I use in other part of program,  I wanted to print the output in a more presentable like this:

```
This is the order history of Andrew.
            Jeans Wallet Perfume Jacket
Purchase 1:  2       4
Purchase 2:                 2
```

Comment: Use a nested loop to print the quantities of each item in the appropriate column.

Comment: tried that but, the each order is order_history like this {'Jeans':2, 'Wallet': 4} is represented as one element of list i.e, order_history[0] is {'Jeans':2, 'Wallet': 4}. I don't have any idea how I can iterate through it.

Comment: Just saying, if you're going to storing tabular data, you might want to look into some libraries like [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a nested loop to print the quantity of each item, by looping over the keys of `product_dict`. Use `end=''` to print all the quantities on the same line, and use fixed-width fields in the formatting string to make everything line up.

```
product_dict = {"Jeans": 150, "Jacket": 300, "Perfume": 50, "Wallet": 125, "Glasses": 100}
#product dictonary with prices
order_history = {'Andrew':[{'Jeans':2, 'Wallet': 4}, {'Perfume':2}], 'Max':[{'Jacket': 3}]}
c_name = 'Andrew'

print(f'The following is order history of {c_name}')
print(' ' * 12, end='')
for product in product_dict:
    print(f'{product:10}', end='')
print()
key = order_history[c_name]
for i, items in enumerate(key, 1):
    print(f'Purchase {i}:  ', end='')
    for product in product_dict:
        if product in items:
            print(f'{items[product]:<10}', end='')
        else:
            print(' ' * 10, end='')
    print()
```

Answer (score 4):

This is more of a console display issue rather than a python issue.

You could potentially use a library for this, such as Textualize/rich. I don't want to give you the full answer, just lead you in the right direction as it appears you are learning:

```
from rich.console import Console
from rich.table import Table

console = Console()

table = Table(show_header=True, header_style="bold magenta")
table.add_column("Jeans", style="dim", width=12)
table.add_column("Jacket")
table.add_column("Perfume", justify="right")
table.add_column("Wallet", justify="right")
#add more columns as necessary


#iterate over your order history to add rows

table.add_row(
  
)


console.print(table)
```

In my opinion, creating a table in the console would look best.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accommodate additions to your dictionary with arbitrary length product names:

```
product_dict = {"Jeans": 150, "Jacket": 300, "Perfume": 50, "Wallet": 125, "Glasses": 100}
skus = list(product_dict)
width = 0
for sku in skus:
    l = len(sku)
    if l > width:
        width = l
width = width + 2
pl = len('Purchase XX')
h = ' '.center(pl + 1,' ')
for sku in skus:
    h = h + sku.center(width,' ')

#product dictonary with prices    
order_history = {'Andrew':[{'Jeans':2, 'Wallet': 4}, {'Perfume':2}], 'Max':[{'Jacket': 3}]}
c_name = input('customer name: ')

print('The following is order history of', c_name)
print(h)
key = order_history[c_name]
for i in range(len(key)):
    s = ''
    for sku in skus:
        if sku in list(key[i]):
            s = s + str(key[i][sku]).center(width,' ')
        else:
            s = s + ' '.center(width,' ')
    print('Purchase ' + str(i + 1).rjust(2,' ') + ' ' + s)
```

You'll get something like this:

```
The following is order history of Andrew
              Jeans    Jacket  Perfume   Wallet  Glasses 
Purchase  1     2                          4             
Purchase  2                       2
```